# Google Piechart: How to show values instead of percentage?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to show values instead of percentage in Google Chart PieChart slices?

Thanks,

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes. you can. Just set `pieSliceText` in the options like this

```
var options = {
    width: 450,
    height: 300,
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieSliceText: 'value'
};​
```

Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html#Example